# Angular material get primary color in custom component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm having an issue with Angular Material. I've defined a custom theme following the official documentation. Then, I defined a custom component and, following the guide, I tried to retrieve the primary color provided by my theme.

However, I noticed that the code inside the mixin is not being taken into account. Can you help me understand what I might be doing wrong?

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components

theme.css

```
@use 'sass:map';
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();

$tango-blue-palette: (
  /**/
);
$verdigris-palette: (
  /**/
);
$indian-red-palette: (
  /**/
);

$m6smart-primary: mat.define-palette($tango-blue-palette, 800, 500, 900);
$m6smart-accent: mat.define-palette($verdigris-palette, 500, 300, 700);
$m6smart-warn: mat.define-palette($indian-red-palette, 400);

$light-theme: mat.define-light-theme(
  (
    color: (primary: $m6smart-primary, accent: $m6smart-accent, avvisa: $m6smart-warn),
  )
);
$light-theme: map.set($light-theme, color, background, background, #f9f9fa);
@include mat.all-component-themes($light-theme);

$dark-theme: mat.define-dark-theme(
  (
    color: (primary: $m6smart-primary, accent: $m6smart-accent, avvisa: $m6smart-warn),
    typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
    density: 0,
  )
);
$dark-theme: map.set($dark-theme, color, background, background, #32333e);

.darkMode {
  @include mat.all-component-colors($dark-theme);
}
```

_breadcrumbs-theme.component.scss

```
@use 'sass:map';
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

a,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:visited {
  color: red;
}

@mixin color($theme) {
  a,
  a:hover,
  a:active,
  a:visited {
    color: blue !important; //mat.get-theme-color($theme, warn, darker);
  }
}
```

The a element is show red